# How to change a button to a loading icon that animates?

Tags: c#, wpf, asynchronous

The title says it all...

I am honestly at lost here... I'm using WPF to do this. I've tried using background worker, Thread, Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(), and async-await to achieve my goal but to no avail... I settled in async-await since I think this is simpler to post here in SO...

Here's my code:

C# code behind:

```
private async void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
    RollingIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

    await DoLogin();

    btnLogin.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    RollingIcon.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private Task DoLogin()
{
  return TaskEx.Run(() => {
      //code for validation if no nulls
      this.ViewModel.ValidateUserCredentials();
  });
}
```

XAML

```
<Button x:Name="btnLogin"
        Content="Login"
        Margin="10,10,10,0"
        IsDefault="True"
        Foreground="White"
        Background="#FF757575"
        Click="btnLogin_Click" />
<local:SpinningAnimation x:Name="RollingIcon" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10,10,10,0" Visibility="Collapsed">

</local:SpinningAnimation >
```

Obviously, `System.InvalidOperationException` will pop up since the ViewModel is created in the main thread when I'm trying to populate it on another thread.

Please guide me to the right path and save me from the Dark side...

Anything will be appreciated.

TIA

Comment: If you are using MVVM Pattern, I think you got something horribly wrong. You're trying to run a task in the View (UI-Thread) from your ViewModel? Even the Visibilty should be bound to Properties.. if you need Hidden, use another Converter. For the Login I would write a Service Class or something like that and binding the Button to a Command that uses it.

Comment: @Daniel - That gave me an idea. Will try it! Thanks! Though that downvote really hurt so much..

Comment: No problem.. for better understanding see some (basic) MVVM examples for your purpose, like many already posted here. If you really need to acces something from another Thread, you can use a Dispatcher Invoke.. but before that it would be better to understand threading. I didn't give you a downvote, lol

Answer (score 0):

Answering this question:

Thanks to Daniel, I realized that placing a new thread in VM is more proper than the View. I reworked my design and this is how it looks like now:

VM

```
 public void ValidateUserCredentials()
        {
            BackgroundWorker bgw = new BackgroundWorker();
            bgw.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(Bgw_DoWork);
            bgw.RunWorkerCompleted += Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted;
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
        private void Bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (IsLoginSuccessful == true)
            {
                _controller.CloseViewModel(this);
                _controller.InitWincollect();
            }
        }

        private void Bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            ShowBusyIcon = true;
            IsLoginSuccessful = _controller.ValidateUserCredential();
        }
        bool _isLoginSuccessful = false;
        private bool _showBusyIcon;

        public bool ShowBusyIcon
        {
            get { return _showBusyIcon; }
            set { _showBusyIcon = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowBusyIcon"); }
        }

        public bool IsLoginSuccessful
        {
            get { return _isLoginSuccessful; }
            set { _isLoginSuccessful = value; NotifyPropertyChanged("IsLoginSuccessful"); }
        }
```

View (XAML)

```
        <Button x:Name="btnLogin"
                Content="Login" Visibility="{Binding ShowBusyIcon, Converter={StaticResource inverseVisibilityConverter}}" />
        <local:SpinningAnimation  x:Name="RollingIcon" 
                                  Grid.Column="1" 
                                  Width="40" Height="40" 
                                  Margin="10,10,10,0" 
                                  Visibility="{Binding ShowBusyIcon, Converter={StaticResource  bool2VisibilityConverter}}" 
                                  Style="{DynamicResource SpinningAnimationStyle1}" />
```